# Which Hindu god left the Earth last?

Tags: kali-yuga

In Hinduism, there are many gods. Among all of them, 
who last left the Earth?

I am not referring to god men like Shirdi Sai Baba or Adi Shankaracharya

Comment: Question is opinion based as different sects will consider other gods as not god.

Comment: The Buddha avatar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether Buddha is considered as Vishnu's avtaar or not it'd be either Sri Krishna or Bhagwan Buddha.

Some avtaars are still considered to be on earth (Sri Hanuman being staying near Trikut parvat).

And last would be Kalki, who would appear on earth at the end of KaliYug.

Comment: Add some citations @user040620

Answer (score 2):

Krishna was the last god to leave the earth because he is an avatar of vishnu.

As said at [this website](http://udaypai.in/krishnas-bodily-departure/), "18th February 3102 BCE Friday...". This is the earliest known departure of a god, which was right before Kali Yuga started.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It should be Buddha Avathar, or Krishna because some believe that Buddha Avathar is the last avatar, or Krishna is the last. Order can be Krishna Buddha, and Kalki, or Krishna, Balarama, and Kalki